# Inserting an image in a <pre> tag

Tags: support, markdown, pre

How can I insert a linked image in a `<pre/>` tag? I've tried:

```
<pre>
![my picture][1]
</pre>
[1]: http://lh6.ggpht.com/pic.jpg
```

But this isn't working.

*P.S. Please don't downvote the crap out of this question if it has been asked/answered before. I searched, couldn't find the answer, but if you know of the answer on another question, please just kindly point me that way.* 谢谢!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way would be to use the <img> HTML tag, because block elements like <pre> are supposed to block Markdown, according to the spec.

```
<pre>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6JgD.png" />
</pre>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what i needed!

Comment: Oh, I have to wait 6 minutes before accepting :( So that means you have to wait 6 minutes too :)

Comment: I just noticed that your smilies form an open and closing set of parentheses, @Otaku